Run multiple projects in vs code
I ran a project(html) it opened on chrome but the problem is when I try to open another project (html) it shows "Server already running in different workspace" help me run different projects at the same time in vs code.

You haven't given us much to go on, but ChatGPT suggests that it is a problem with a language server being used improperly.

Why dont you just use a Localhost like Xampp? There you can run multiple Projects at once.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can use extensions like Live Server, and you can install as many of them as you like. As long as they don’t use the same port, you can have multiple projects running.
Furthermore, since you're using HTML, you don’t actually need a server to view it in the browser. You can simply drag and drop your .html file into the browser, and it will display.vscode extension live server 

i actually have live server installed but it still doesn't work either, earlier i used to follow a course on udemy and that person provided all the required folders and it worked quite well without that issue but now when im doing my own projects it doesn't work

As I mentioned earlier, you can't run multiple projects simultaneously with Live Server alone. You will need to use extensions that provide similar functionality. For each project, you can use one of these extensions that are available.
Here is a video presenting 4 alternatives to Live Server.
